# Edit project file in Visual Studio 2010 using TFS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, csproj

I've got a solution checked out from our TFS2010 system and want to edit the .csproj file itself in native text format (and not via the Project->Properties). Until we introduced TFS2010 I just edited the .csproj file in a simple text editor. How can I edit the project file regarding TFS2010 CheckIn/CheckOut mechanisms?

Many Thanks, Konrad

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access the project files by right clicking the project in the solution and selecting "Unload Project" then right click on it again and select "Edit MyProject.csproj". To open the project again, right click and select "Reload Project".

Comment: And then TFS recognized the changes? Well, that's one solution.

Another solution a colleague came up with is to install the TFS Power Tools. They enable checkout/checkin from the explorer and therewith an editing of files outside of VS.

Comment: You could also do a manual checkout from TFS, edit it in Notepad and then check it back in.

Comment: Jim's answer seems to be the most reliable work of doing this.

Comment: This does not work if your solution only has a single project (at least not in VS2010)